# Name of the window doesn't get printed

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

The following program is meant to print the name of the window that has focus or at least the name of the command prompt where the program is running.But it prints only one character which is `W`. Why is it so ? Where am I making a mistake ?

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
 TCHAR title[500];
 int i=0;
 while(i<10) {
   GetWindowText(GetForegroundWindow(), title, 500);
   printf("%s\n",title);
   i++;
   system("pause");
 }
}
```

Comment: Stop `TCHAR`ing already and use `wchar_t`. It's 2012.

Answer (score 2):

I dare to guess that `TCHAR` expands to `wchar_t` or `short` to support Unicode (UTF-16, to be more precise) and that's the source of the problem.

In UTF16, the character 'W' is represented by 2 bytes: 87 (ASCII code for 'W') and 0.

If you try to print a UTF-16 string beginning with 'W' with the regular `printf()`, `printf()` will reinterpret that UTF-16 string as "W\0" and stop printing right after 'W'.

To print strings of `TCHAR` you should use [`_tprintf()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc7014hz.aspx) instead.

Comment: `title` after going through `GetWindowText` is a UTF-16 encoded string ?

Comment: Why not? See [`GetWindowText()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633520%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) description: `LPTSTR lpString`. Can you see a 'T' in it?

Answer (score 0):

Because it is a TCHAR it can be ansi or unicode. Use _tprintf instead printf

Answer (score 0):

If you want to continue using ANSI version with `printf`, use `GetWindowTextA` and replace `TCHAR` with `char` because Windows have 2 set of API that work with strings:

1) version (A) that work with ANSI strings and take `char*` or `const char*` as input.

2) version (W) that work with wide strings and take `wchar_t*` or `const wchar_t*` as input. Since this is native version of the function it is slightly faster and also it can work with Unicode strings.

Since `_UNICODE` is defined in your project, `TCHAR` will be mapped to `wchar_t` and `GetWindowText` will be mapped to `GetWindowTextW`, so you that use `printf` to work with narrow strings can't print `wchar_t*` with '`%s`, you should either use `_tprintf` or stop using `TCHAR` and directly call version of API that best match your need (here call `GetWindowTextA`) for example you can use this:

```
wchar_t title[500];
GetWindowTextW(GetForegroundWindow(), title, 500);
printf("%ls\n", title);
```